# Custom Keyboard in c# Xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I made a custom digital keyboard, I want to hide the system keyboard, how can I do it in xamarin c#?

I made a custom keyboard to use, and I want to disable the system keyboard for good. I would like to know, how can I do it in xamarin android c#

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can rewrite the method `OnTouchEvent` to close the keyboard on the device.

```
 public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            EditText Etusername = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Etname);
            imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Etusername.WindowToken, 0);
            return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
        }
```

Second, you can create a class HideAndShowKeyboard.cs

```
 internal class HideAndShowKeyboard
    {
   /*
    * Shows the soft keyboard
    */
        public void showSoftKeyboard(Android.App.Activity activity, View view)
        {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            view.RequestFocus();
            inputMethodManager.ShowSoftInput(view, 0);
            
        }

        /*
         * Hides the soft keyboard
         */
        public void hideSoftKeyboard(Android.App.Activity activity)
        {
            var currentFocus = activity.CurrentFocus;
            if (currentFocus != null)
            {
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                inputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can use the class like this.

```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            EditText Etusername = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Etusername);
            var hideAndShowKeyboard = new HideAndShowKeyboard();
            hideAndShowKeyboard.showSoftKeyboard(this, Etusername);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, I forgot to mention that I only want to use the digital keyboard in one form, not in each form.